# Prove that there exists a line passing through M$(\alpha,\beta)$ which is tangent to the graph of $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, tangent-line, rolles-theorem

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ be a function continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Let M$(\alpha,\beta)$ be a point on the line passing through the points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ with $\alpha\notin [a,b]$.

Prove that there exists a line passing through M$(\alpha,\beta)$ which is tangent to the graph of $f$.

My Attempt:
I think this is an applicaton of Rolle's or Lagrange's Mean Value theorems but I am not able to frame the proper function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below, I'll show that the result can be shown using Rolle's Theorem.

Let $P$ be the point $(a,f(a))$, and let $Q$ be the point $(b,f(b))$. We're given that $M=(\alpha,\beta)$ is a point on line $PQ$ with $\alpha\notin[a,b]$.

For each $x\in[a,b]$, let $g(x)$ be the slope between $M$ and the point $(x,f(x))$. It follows that

$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)-\beta}{x-\alpha}$$

for all $x\in[a,b]$. From the fact that $\alpha\notin[a,b]$, we get that $g(x)$ is defined for all $x\in[a,b]$. It follows that the function $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. From the fact that $M$ is on line $PQ$, we get that $g(a)=g(b)$. Note, that our function $g$ therefore satisfies the hypotheses of Rolle's Theorem. Hence $g'(t)=0$ for some $t\in(a,b)$.

Using the quotient rule, we get that

$$\begin{align*}
g'(x) &= \frac{(x-\alpha)f'(x)-(f(x)-\beta)}{(x-\alpha)^2} \\
&= \frac{f'(x)}{(x-\alpha)}-\frac{(f(x)-\beta)}{(x-\alpha)^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{x-\alpha}\cdot\left(f'(x)-\frac{f(x)-\beta}{x-\alpha}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{x-\alpha}\cdot\left(f'(x)-g(x)\right) \\
&= \frac{f'(x)-g(x)}{x-\alpha}
\end{align*}$$

And so by Rolle's Theorem, there is a $t\in(a,b)$ with $g'(t)=0$. Hence

$$\frac{f'(t)-g(t)}{t-\alpha}=g'(t)=0.$$

It follows that $f'(t)-g(t)=0$. Hence $f'(t)=g(t)$.

If we let $R$ be the point $(t,f(t))$, then the slope of line $MR$ is $g(t)$. Also, the slope of the tangent line to the curve $y=f(x)$ at $R$ is $f'(t)$. It follows that $MR$ is the tangent line to the curve $y=f(x)$ at $R$.